# IOS - save or cache DrawRect image

Tags: ios, drawrect, save

I have a UIView with lots of image is drawn from drawRect when drawn finished, i wanna save(cache) all of image

How to save(cache) all of image in drawRect or something like that!

Thank everyone for looking this article.

Comment: Couldn't you just put the code in a separate method and call it whenever you need the rectangle drawn?

Comment: I add subview UIView with a lots of image inside uiscrollview when uiscrollview scroll i call uiview again, because uiview will be redraw image, i don't want redraw image

Answer (score 0):

If you cache blindly in the name of performance, it can have very *negative* performance costs. Caching isn't free -- use it judiciously in order to achieve the best balance of resources. Ideally, you would consider several other alternative approaches to determine which suits your exact needs best.

One quick/efficient approach would be `CALayer.shouldRasterize`.